# Functions & if / else

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm new to Javascript and I'm currently doing [this question](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-6LzGd/2/4?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661) on codecademy. When trying to run the code, I keep getting an error as such: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token". Could anyone give an explanation why?

Here's my code:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours);
if (function(numHours) >= 8) {
    return "You're getting planety of sleep! Maybe even too much";
} else {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

Comment: They have a qa forum. I'd say thats a more appropriate please to seek help. http://www.codecademy.com/forums/javascript-beginner-en-6LzGd/2

Answer (score 4):

Your code needs a little bit of refactoring to perform correctly. In this case, you want to define the function `sleepCheck` outside of the if statement with `numHours` as the parameter to the function:

```
function sleepCheck(numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        return "You're getting planety of sleep! Maybe even too much";
    } else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
}

console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

Functions should be wrapped in curly braces `{ ... }`. This is how the browser's JavaScript parser knows where the function begins and where it ends. This step is crucial because the brackets surround the code that will execute when the function is invoked.

**DEMO:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/6CRB6/)

To see the demo in action use the <kbd>F12</kbd> key to open your browser's console. The messages will appear in there. If you're not familiar with the console yet or are uncomfortable with it, you can substitute the `console.log` for `alert`. This is not usually recommended though. I only suggest this because you said you are a beginner. You should become a fan of the console and all of it's glory. Learn to use the console as the console will be your lifeline for all your debugging needs.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a function called sleepCheck that takes a parameter called numHours, and in your code your not doing it.

Do something like:

```
function sleepCheck(numHours) {
   if (numHours >= 8)
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax isn't right. You didn't define the function declaration `sleepCheck` correctly. The function itself should wrap all of its contents, and any content should be within the functions curly braces. You have a function mixed with an if statement.

It should be

```
function sleepCheck(numHours){
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        return "You're getting planety of sleep! Maybe even too much";
    } else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
}
```

Also, remember to do something with the return value, simply calling this function won't give you a result unless you capture the return value:

```
console.log( sleepCheck(8) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're calling a function incorrectly attempts thus hope you work

```
 function sleepCheck(numHours) {
        if (numHours >= 8) {
            return "You're getting .....";
        } else {
            return "Get some more .....";
        }
    }

    console.log(sleepCheck(8));....
```